# Fetched data is visible in Network tab but getting an error in console log

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am able to fetch some data from the server but unable to view the fetched data in console.log. I am facing below error. I am already returning the data in the form of an array. So what exactly has to be done to get the fetched data into console log?

**Error:**

```
react-dom.development.js:14757 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). 
    If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

**Code on front end in React:**

```
import "./index.css";
function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
    <form>
<div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" className="form-control" />
  <small className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" className="form-control"/>
</div>
<div className="form-group form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" />
  <label className="form-check-label" >Check me out</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" onClick={fetch}  className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
    </form>
    function fetch(){
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/",{
        mode:"no-cors",
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then((data)=>{return data.json()})
      .then((data)=>{console.log(data)})
      .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
    }
    </header>
    
  </div>
  ) 
}

export default App;
```

**Code on backend in Node.js:**

```
const http = require("http");
const express=require("express");
let app = express();

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":JSON});
    res.end(JSON.stringify([
        {
            "name":"LM10",
            "team":"PSG",
        },
        {
            "name":"CR7",
            "team":"ManU",
        }
]));
}).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick question, why are you using the JSON.stringify() in the backend, then you are converting it into a string object. I would try to remove that and check if you can get back an array of objects. or use `res.send()` or `res.json()` instead.
Good Luck

Comment: res.json is not working for some reason. it says it is not a function despite installing express. That is why I have used JSON.stringify(). Also I have tried removing the conversion to JSON in .then method but there is no difference

Comment: `res.send is not a function`. This is the error I get when I try to use `res.send()` or `res.json()`